# Differentiation of $u^{T}Su$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I want to differentiate $u^{T}Su$ wrt $u$ where $u$ is $n$ x $1$ and $S$ is $n$ x $n$matrix . So I did the following . 
Since $u^{T}Su$ is a number , I wrote its expression ie

$$ f = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_iS_{ik}u_k$$

Now if I find $\frac{df}{du_j} $ for any $j$ then the job is done .

So $$\frac{df}{du_j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{jk}u_k+\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iS_{ij}$$
$$\frac{df}{du_j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}S_{ji}u_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iS_{ij}$$

Therefore the differentiation is $$(S+S^{T})u$$

Am I right ? If I am not please help me with the differentiation . Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is correct. However, be careful with the summation indices, you've written some of them wrongly.

Comment: @Imanol Are they correct now ? (I have updated them)

Comment: Yeah, they're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is correct. I prefer to write the derivative of this kind of map down with an application to a vector. So if $F(u) = u^TSu$ you will get

$$dF(u)< v > = v^T Su + u^TSv$$